# Use PowerShell to remotely bulk override a file and restart a certain service

Tags: powershell, scripting

I need your help.

I need to write a script that will from a windows server,
Will connect to a list of servers (provided by a csv that has IP Addresses)
on those servers will overwrite a file located either on 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Folder1 or C:\Program Files\Folder1
Taking the correct version from the server Running the script from D:\
and then restart a service called sname1.

(we can assume all target servers have the WinRM Active)
Your help will be greatly appriciated.

What I have so far is this, but I'm not sure it's correct assuming I'm working with IP Addresses and not Hostnames (Hostnames aren't an option as I'm not using this in a domain environment)

```
$servers=Get-Content D:\List.txt
foreach ($server in $servers)
  {
    if (Test-Path "\\$_\c$\Program Files\Folder1")
    {
        Copy-Item \\127.0.0.1\D$\file1.ini "\\$_\c$\Program Files\Folder1\file1.ini"
    }
    if (Test-Path "\\$_\c$\Program Files (x86)\Folder1")
    {
        Copy-Item \\127.0.0.1\D$\file1.ini "\\$_\c$\Program Files (x86)\Folder1\file1.ini"
    }
    Restart-Service -InputObject $(Get-Service -Computer $server -Name sname1)
  }
```

Comment: For starters you are using foreach and not using your variable `$server` in the loop where you are testing paths. Replace that where you are using `$_`. Is your file supposed to be in the x86 directory? I will end up in the other always because of how you ordered the if statements. .

Comment: Thanks for your input.
the situation has changed a little as I was informed that the file I'll be getting is a CSV one that has the following fields Alias (The IP of the Server), Domain, username and Password.
I therefore modified my starting script to this: http://pastebin.com/3imB22P7
How does that look?

Comment: Also if the file already exists you probably need `Copy-Item -Force`

Answer (score 0):

REF:

```
$servers=Import-Csv E:\Temp\serverlist.csv
$Source = "D:\file1.ini"
foreach ($server in $servers)
  {
    $Password  = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force -String "$server.Password"
    $User = "$server.Domain\$server.Usernaem"
    $credentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user,$password
    if (Test-Path "\\$server.Alias\c$\Program Files\Folder1")
    {
        $Destination = "\\$server.Alias\c$\Program Files\Folder1"
    }
    if (Test-Path "\\$server.Alias\c$\Program Files (x86)\Folder1")
    {
        $Destination = "\\$server.Alias\c$\Program Files (x86)\Folder1"
    }
    Copy-Item $Source -Destination $Destination -Credential $credentials -Force
    Restart-Service -InputObject $(Get-Service -Computer $server,Alias -Name sname1)
  }
```

Note that you CANNOT access properties or methods of variables if you enclose it in quotes. For example, if you say;

```
$test = 1234
Write-Output "House $test.ToString()"
```

You will get the output "House 1234.ToString()" because the method is not resolved, it just assumes it's a string. You need to either split it up or enclose it:

```
Write-Output ("House " + $test.ToString())
Write-Output "House $($test.ToString())"
```

Additionally you've misspelled UserName when declaring `$User`. Fix those up and it should work fine.

I recommend checking out Microsoft's MVAs [PowerShell 3.0 JumpStart](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/getting-started-with-powershell-30-jump-start-8276?l=r54IrOWy_2304984382) and [Advanced Tools & Scripting](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/advanced-tools-scripting-with-powershell-30-jump-start-8277?l=WOWaGUWy_8604984382) as they explain a lot of this stuff, get you into good habits and are actually pretty fun to watch.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the Input.
The situation has changed a little and I'm getting a CSV file with the following fields: Alias (which has the IP), Domain (will designate '.' if not in a domain), username and password. I therefore changed mny script to this: pastebin.com/3imB22P7
Will this work?

Comment: Needed more detail than I could put in a comment. Updated answer.